# Why LinearSVC works so bad on this dataset?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I just generated a dataset, and from the scatter plot I think these scatters are quite separable. But I really don't know why the Linear SVC-sklearn worked very bad. The dataset scatters plot and the SVC result are below:

[scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYazV.png)
[Linear SVC result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFnaW.png)

The code I use is like

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC    
svc = LinearSVC()    
model = svc.fit(X, y)
```

Could anyone help me with that problem? I really think SVM should have a better result.

The dataset csv file is here:
[data csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FkksGM5XM9BrX3vthOlwppSWaXEK3nu9/view?usp=sharing)

The first two columns are x and y respectively, and the third column is the data label.

Comment: Providing the dataset could allow others to reproduce the problem and test potential solutions.

Comment: I'm very new to stack overflow. I just post the google drive link of this dataset. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is centered set your `fit_intercept` to `False`. You might do better here with less regularization, by increasing the cost of the error (`C=100`):

```
svc = LinearSVC(fit_intercept=False, C=100)
```

Comment: That works! Thanks so much. Could you please spend a little time explaining why we don't need fit_intercept here? I see many examples only set the C value.

Comment: It has to do with the way the intercept is incorporated into the optimization, it gets added as a feature and regularized with the rest. I always prefer explicitly preprocessing by centering the data whenever possible, I’ve sometimes gotten nasty results when I don’t (especially with PCA).

Comment: Exactly, the data I get is PCA processed. Your answer is really helpful. Thanks again!